# Parameter Passing in C-like

Tags: parameter-passing

```
int i, a[] = {0, 1, 2};

void foo(int x) { 
  i++;
  x++;
  cout << a[0] << " " << a[1] << " " << a[2];
}

void main() {  
  i = 0;
  foo(a[i]);
}
```

So, the printing output will be:

- By **value-result**: `0 - 1 - 2`
- By **reference**: `1 - 1 - 2`
- By **name**: `0 - 2 - 2`
- By **constant reference**: `0 - 1 - 2`

Right ?

Answer (score 0):

Beware, the `cout` stream and `<<` operators are pure C++ primitives, you are NOT in C !

You also have to understand that side-effect inside a sequence of `cout << foo << bar << fuzz;` will produce a totally impredictable output depending on the choices made by the compiler (and NOT triggered by the language specification because the variables are supposed to stay constant along the evaluation of the expression).

To illustrate what I am saying, try to compile the following small program (`example.cpp`):

```
#include  <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
   int i = 0;
  cout << "i++: " << i++ << i++ << i++ << i++ << endl;
  i = 0;
  cout << "++i: " << ++i << ++i << ++i << ++i << endl;
  cout << "The address of i is: " << &i << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

When compiled with `g++ -o example example.cpp`, you should get something like:

```
i++: 3210
++i: 4321
The address of i is: 0xbfb1c44c
```

Then, try to compile it with `g++ -O2 -o example example.cpp`, you should get something like:

```
i++: 3210
++i: 4444
The address of i is: 0xbf9af0cc
```

In fact, the difference of these two execution comes from the fact that once you trigger the optimization in `g++`, the compiler assumes that you conform to the specification of C++ and that there will be no side-effect inside the `cout << ... << endl;` expression. So, it will use the last value of `i` all the time.

Comment: yup, actually I just want to know some basic passing para mechanism, not too deep , so u can call it C++-like language

Comment: Well, then you just took the wrong example... (bad luck!). So, either split the `cout << ...` into pieces, or take another example. Note also that in C++, having `x` or `&x` as function/method argument will change the way it is passed to the body of the function/method. Anyway, it would worth to restart another question from scratch, this one is a bit too messy.